# How about making the review process for First Posts, Late answers, and Triage blind?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

The current process of reviewing [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts), [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers), and [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) allows reviewers to click the link and see the actual post.

This leaves the space for a reviewer to make an unfair review by jumping to the original post to see which category can it be assigned without actually giving it a fair deal.

Moreover, the same thing is valid even for the audits, which can also be openly viewed just by a click, undermining the audit itself.

Therefore, what if the review process for First Posts, Late Answers, and Triage is made blind, by hiding the link to the reviewed post?

**EDIT:** As termed by @honk, "robo-reviewers": Such reviewers can easily dodge by only an additional click which does not even double their game-time.

Well, if not making it *blind*, I am not sure what could be the best possible option to address this anomaly.

Comment: "make an unfair review by jumping to the original post to see which category can it be assigned without actually giving it a fair deal" I'm not clear what you mean by this outside the context of audits. Score is already shown in the queues, and other information would seem to tend toward more accurate judgment, not more biased or easily-swayed.

Comment: "I'm not clear what you mean by this outside the context of audits." Well, the main concern is outside the audits. If a post is sure to be a non-audit (a review) post, and when there is no evaluation of each review, a reviewer can easily categorize (eg. up/down vote) it according to her/his mood and ignore the merit.

Comment: Well, this can already be done outside the queues anyway. Inside the queues there's at least the chance of someone noticing bad reviews and getting them review-banned by a mod. What's more, there's no point in voting to finish a review out: it's never the only action that will give you credit for it.

Comment: to me, "Well, this can already be done outside the queues anyway." this is something totally different and it is vandalism, "Inside the queues there's at least the chance of someone noticing bad reviews and getting them review-banned by a mod." Yes, there is just a **chance**. "What's more, there's no point in voting to finish a review out: it's never the only action that will give you credit for it." voting is just an example. But it also impacts posts.

Comment: I disagree that there's no similarity between someone voting randomly in First Posts and someone voting randomly elsewhere. They're almost exactly the same, except that in /review, voting is *one* of the ways to switch from No Action Needed to I'm Done without visible action… not that this is important for getting that all-important gold badge. The point is, this isn't a new vulnerability. If someone was going to vote randomly, they can already do that without leaving traces in /review. Somehow, the site keeps running.

Comment: It's not worthwhile to obsess over relatively minor special cases of much broader vulnerabilities that we've already resigned ourselves to weathering as best we can.

Answer (score 11):

The review queues leave out a fair amount of information, such as answers to questions, and competing answers, which *can* be useful for reviewers. Many actions are also unavailable when viewing from the queues, such as voting and answering. As for the audits, [those aren't supposed to be difficult anyway.](/q/288046/6388243)

Answer (score 3):

Audits are mainly for catching inattentive reviewers or so-called robo-reviewers (which are blindly approving all posts by hammering the approval button just to quickly get a high review count and the associated badges).

> The current process of reviewing First Posts, Late Answers, and Triage allows reviewers to click the link and see the actual post.

If a reviewer does this, then that user is usually interested in reviewing correctly. Opening a post outside of the review queue is actually a legitimate measure to gather additional information around a post in order to do a proper review.

> Therefore, what if the review process for First Posts, Late Answers, and Triage is made blind, by hiding the link to the reviewed post?

The review queues present limited information about a Q&A, because that information is usually sufficient to do a proper *and efficient* review. The link exists for borderline cases, where more context would help to correctly review the post. To put it another way: The review queues are not there for making reviews difficult, they are made for making them efficient. It therefore makes no sense to hide the link to the actual post.

Comment: "**robo-reviewers** (which are blindly approving all posts just to quickly get a high review count and the associated badges)" **Yes, my main concern is about this type of reviewers.**

Comment: @tod: Robo-reviewers, by definition, don't click that link, because they are reviewing blindly. They are hammering the approval button in order to "review" 20 posts within roughly half a minute. If reviewers click that link, they have to take a look at the post, close the tab/window again, and hit the correct button. I guess this takes at least 2-3 minutes. As I understood from previous discussions, the vast majority of users, which don't review properly, don't do that. So, the problem you describe seems not to be big enough to need a solution.